# TCP reliability in case of interposition of packet

Tags: sockets, tcp

This question is a (sort of) follow-up to [Intercepting/Rerouting TCP SYN packets to C++ program in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594162/intercepting-rerouting-tcp-syn-packets-to-c-program-in-linux).

The question is: If SYN or any other TCP packet is modified (say the source IP address/port is changed) before it is sent to the network (i.e. on the source), what effect will it have on TCP reliability (for example if the packet is lost)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect will be exactly the same as for not modified packet - the network stack will timeout and re-try, and eventually give up, and return with `ETIMEDOUT` from [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html).